# SQL(Snowflake) - SUMIFS but condition is set per that row in multiple column conditions

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sumifs

I have a table

```
|---------------------|------------------|-----------|
|      Live-Date      |     Live_Cohort  | Unit_Count| Desired_Output (Weighting of Unit Count)
|---------------------|------------------|-----------|
|         3/1/19             Q1 2019            5          56%
          3/1/19             Q1 2019            4          44%
          4/1/19             Q1 2019            3          100%
          4/1/19             Q2 2019            4          29%
          4/1/19             Q2 2019            10         71%
```

How do I write a query that acts as a sumifs function in excel that counts the weighting of the unit count in each row with the total unit count that matches the live_date and live_cohort in that row.

For example in row 1, 5 units accounts for 56% of the total units in the live date of 3/1/19 and Q1/2019 and do that for every row as shown in the desired_output column

Answer (score 0):

I think you want window functions:

```
select t.*,
       units_count * 100.0 / sum(units_count) over (partition by live_date, live_cohort) as percentage
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think that using window function might get you what you need.  Something like:

```
select 
        live-date,live-cohort, unit_count, 
        100 * ratio_to_report(unit_count) over (partition by Live-Date) as unit_weighting
    from your_table
    order by live-date,live-cohort, unit_count;
```